# R combine different variables of different length to one to generate a control group

Tags: r, statistics, statistics-bootstrap

I am creating a new sample using bootstrap to generate a control group with control for age and gender. every variable have a different length of number between 2 values to eight values

```
control_40_50_HRV_female2 <- abs(parametric_bootstrap_boot2(control_40_50_HRV_female_SDNN))
control_50_60_HRV_male2 <- abs(parametric_bootstrap_boot2(control_50_60_HRV_male_SDNN))
control_50_60_HRV_female2 <-abs(parametric_bootstrap_boot2(control_50_60_HRV_female_SDNN))
control_60_70_HRV_male2 <- abs(parametric_bootstrap_boot2(control_60_70_HRV_male_SDNN))
control_60_70_HRV_female2 <-abs(parametric_bootstrap_boot2(control_60_70_HRV_female_SDNN))
control_70_80_HRV_male2 <-abs(parametric_bootstrap_boot2(control_70_80_HRV_male_SDNN))
```

how can I put them all in one group (one variable)? so I can start doing a t-test ? I hope this is clear

this a sample output for the variables

```
> control_40_50_HRV_female2
[1]  29.08388 102.49869
> control_50_60_HRV_male2
[1]  36.81686 127.47986  13.40681
> control_50_60_HRV_female2
[1] 25.50313
> control_60_70_HRV_male2
[1]  39.93050 140.75967  13.89545 316.45988 158.91477
> control_60_70_HRV_female2
[1]  26.27908 106.40483
```

when I run this command

```
out <- stack(mget(ls(pattern = '^control_\\d{2}_\\d{2}_\\w+_')))[2:1]
dim(out)
```

I get this.. which is a list of all the variables I have created from the beginning of the script..

```
> dim(out)
[1] 96683     2
> head(out)
                           ind values
1 control_40_50_HRV_female_BPM  63.48
2 control_40_50_HRV_female_BPM  52.67
3 control_40_50_HRV_female_BPM  88.92
4 control_40_50_HRV_female_BPM  69.04
5 control_40_50_HRV_female_BPM  53.46
6 control_40_50_HRV_female_BPM  63.64
```

while I only need a list of these variable
control_40_50_HRV_female2, control_50_60_HRV_male2 .... control_70_80_HRV_male2

Comment: Your comment `while I only need a list of these variable control_40_50_HRV_female2, control_50_60_HRV_male2` do you need a subset of data i.e. `subset(out, ind %in% c("control_40_50_HRV_female2", "control_50_60_HRV_male2", "control_70_80_HRV_male2"))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `mget` to get the values of the 'control' objects into a `list` and then `stack` it to a two column data.frame

```
out <- stack(mget(ls(pattern = '^control_\\d{2}_\\d{2}_\\w+_')))[2:1]


head(out)
#                        ind    values
#1 control_40_50_HRV_female2  29.08388
#2 control_40_50_HRV_female2 102.49869
#3 control_50_60_HRV_female2  25.50313
#4   control_50_60_HRV_male2  36.81686
#5   control_50_60_HRV_male2 127.47986
#6   control_50_60_HRV_male2  13.40681
```

Comment: and list all the controls variables after pattern = 'control_40_50_HRV_female2,control_50_60_HRV_male2 ...  '

Comment: @EA90 the output is a two column data.frame with one column having the object names `control_40_50_HRV_female2` and the second column with the corresponding values of that object

Comment: Thanks a lot ,, this have created more than 48,000 rows .. any idea why ?

Comment: @EA90 `mget` extracts all those vectors you created in the global env as a `list` of named vectors and the `stack` collapses the list into a two column data.frame with the ind column as the name of the list and the values as the value of each vector

Comment: is there a way to create a list in two columns for theses specific variables above? instead of a list for all the  global env

Comment: @EA90 can you update your post with expected output as it is not clear from your comments

Comment: can you please have a look ,, I have updated the post,, appreciate it

Comment: I have edited the pattern out <- stack(mget(ls(pattern = '^control_\\d{2}_\\d{2}_\\w+male2')))[2:1] this fixed the issue since I already have so many variables starting with control

Comment: @EA90 Okay.  I was thinking that you need all the objects that starts with control followed by _, 2 digits, then _ and 2 digits

Comment: Thanks a lot ,, you were a hug help